# Determine if value is an element of a list in Haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion

I'm trying to write a function that will determine if an element exists in a list, both of which being provided by the user. I think a recursive solution is best. This is what I have:

```
isElement :: a -> [b] -> Bool
isElement a [] = False
isElement a (x:xs) = if a == x then True
                     else isElement a xs
```

But it can't compile. The error is "Couldn't match expected type -a' with actual type -b'".  I don't know what this means or how to fix the problem.

Comment: Your type signature is wrong. `==` requires its operands to have the same type, but you have `a :: a` and `x :: b`.

Comment: And not just any type; `a` needs to be an instance of the `Eq` type class: `isElement :: Eq a => a -> [a] -> Bool`.

Comment: You should always be suspicious when working with `True` or `False` near an `if`. Usually that means the logic could be expressed more directly without an `if`.  In this case, that's true. You could write the body of the second equation as `(a == x) || isElement a xs`.

Comment: I guess this question is for the sake of learning, but otherwise `elem` is a good function to know of.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You code technically works. It's the type signature that's giving you trouble here.

First, here's the working code:

```
isElement :: (Eq a) => a -> [a] -> Bool
isElement a [] = False
isElement a (x:xs) = if a == x then True
                     else isElement a xs
```

I changed two things:

1. The first thing to keep in mind when working with Haskell's linked lists (the datatype that uses `[]`) is that they can only contain elements of the same type. However in your type signature, `a ➞ [b]` you specify that you require your first element to be of type `a` and the ones in your list of type `b`, different from `a`.
2. The second thing is to "enable" equality checks with generic types `a` and `b`, and GHC will give you a warning with the steps to follow in order to fix that:

   ```
   • No instance for (Eq a) arising from a use of ‘=='
     Possible fix:
       add (Eq a) to the context of
         the type signature for:
           isElement :: a -> [a] -> Bool
   ```

   So what it tells us is to specify that the `a` type can be compared!
   And this is fantastic because we can totally do this by giving that clue to the compiler with the `(Eq a) =>` part in our code, that roughly translates to "given this property (Eq) of datatype `a`, [insert type signature here]". (feel free to correct me here, people of StackOverflow!)

Your code works, and reimplementing functions with this kind of explicit recursion is how I learned how it worked in the first place, so don't hesitate to learn by rewriting the stuff you use, then check their sources on Hackage to see how real-world haskellers actually do it.

Have fun learning!